# Is there an option where I can filter a row on some level and then expand further into lower levels if I use the 'hide' option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I have constructed a table with 7 levels.
What I am trying to do is use the *filter* option to find a row (i.e. on level 3) and then *expand* it manually further into lower levels ?
I am using the 'hide' mode, because I don't want to display the irrelevant rows.

These are the configuration settings I am currently using.

```
autoApply: true,
autoExpand: true,
counter: true,     
fuzzy: false,     
hideExpandedCounter: true,  
hideExpanders: false,       
highlight: false,   
leavesOnly: false, 
nodata: false,     
mode: "hide"
```

The problem is that when I filter a row (i.e. on level 3) I cannot expand the row into lower levels. I reckon that a solution is to use the 'dimm' option but I don't want for the irrelevant rows to be visible.

If anyone has a idea how to solve this, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for [`filterBranches(filter, opts)`](https://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/Fancytree.html#filterBranches) instead of `tree.filterNodes()`.

This will keep all descendants of matched nodes visible as well.

See also the [wiki](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/ExtFilter) for details.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. The only thing I would change is that the marked row is not expanded but I can still expand the marked row to lower levels.